# When i used the useState in react Js for password show and hide on icon click there are not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, web-frontend

```
import React,{useState} from "react";


function Password(){

    const [pass,setPass] = useState("password")


    const handleclick =()=>{
        setPass(("password")? "text" : "password")
    
    }
    return(
        <div>
            Password:<span style={{position:"relative"}}><input type={pass} name="" id="" />
            <i onClick={handleclick} style={{position:"absolute", top:"6px" , right:"5px"}} class="fa-solid fa-eye"></i></span>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Password;
```

When i used the useState in react Js for password show and hide on icon click there are not working. I only show the password show once time but i need to show and hide it whenever click the icon

Comment: `("password")? "text" : "password"` results in `"text"` all the time - perhaps you meant `(pass === "password")? "text" : "password"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import React,{useState} from "react";

function Password(){
    const [pass,setPass] = useState(true);
    return(
        <div>
            Password:
            <span style={{position:"relative"}}>
                // input
                <input type={pass?'password':'text'} name="" id="" />
                //icon
                <i onClick={()=>setPass(!pass)} 
                style={{position:"absolute", top:"6px" , right:"5px"}} 
                className="fa-solid fa-eye"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Password;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set your new state based on your previous state.

With the code that you have provided, the input type is set to `'text'` only once and it won't work like a toggle switch, because in your `handleClick()` you are checking a string value to set the new value.

That condition always returns the same results, therefore, it won't work like a toggle switch.

the correct code would be something like this:

```
 const handleclick = () => {
    setPass(prevState => prevState == 'password' ? 'text' : 'password')
 }
```

This way we check the value of the previous state, if it is `'password'` we set it to `'text'`, otherwise, we set it to `'password'`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import React,{useState} from "react";

function Password(){
    const [password, updatePassword] = useState(true);
    return(
        <div>
            Password:
            <span style={{position:"relative"}}>
                // input
                {                
                  pass ? <input type='password' name="" id="" />
                  : <input type='text' name="" id="" />
                }
                //icon
                <i 
                  onClick={() => updatePassword(!password)} 
                  style={{
                    position:"absolute",
                    top:"6px" ,
                    right:"5px"
                  }} 
                  className="fa-solid fa-eye">
                </i>
            </span>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Password;
```